# И(,) о(,) чудо!

Tags: пунктуация

Как и по какому принципу в этом восклицании следует расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В середине предложения легче всего оформить *О, чудо!* как вставную конструкцию, выделив её с помощью тире:

*Мы можем присмотреться внимательно и - о, чудо! - всё оказывается совершенно иным.*

О - междометие, отделяется от последующего слова с помощью запятой или восклицательного знака.

Междометие «о» не отделяется запятой от последующего слова в сочетаниях с обращениями, словами «да» и «нет», а также в сочетаниях «о господи», «о черт», если оно не выделяется интонационно.

Если это не середина предложения, а отдельная конструкция, то тире ставится одно: *И - о, чудо!*

Возможно и обращение к чуду, тогда без запятой: *И - о чудо!*